# how to get time to speak text by TTS

Tags: android, multithreading, time, text-to-speech

I am developing an application where i am using multiple threads and tts.The execution of threads is depends upon time taken by tts to speak the text so my question is,

***Can we get the time in seconds to speak complete text by tts before tts start speaking?***

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a way to find out how long it will take to speak a particular utterance. But if your intention is just to know when an utterance is *done* being spoken, there are callbacks for that.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/UtteranceProgressListener.html#onDone(java.lang.String)

Depending on your use case, that might actually be better. I say that because requests to speak get queued up and might not get spoken immediately. Not to mention that TTS engines are services that run in another process and there's some overhead in requesting that text be spoken. So even if you know that a certain string would take 5 seconds to speak, it wouldn't necessarily be done being spoken 5 seconds after calling `speak()`.